# How can I edit my image tags on docker hub?

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I have a public docker hub repository, automated build linked to a github repo.

I found I misnamed the tag of my last build.

Is that possible to re-edit the image name manually after building process without influencing the image ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the **Automated builds**, manually pulling, re-tagging and pushing won't work.

First, even if you pull and re-tag your image, you cannot push **manually** to an Automated Build. You will end up getting `Error pushing to registry: Authentication is required.`

The true solution would be to go to your `Build Details` Page, Click on `Settings` -> `Automated Build` -> Edit the tag name under `Docker Tag Name` and hit `Save and trigger build`. This will create a new tag and triggers the build.

Secondly, you **cannot** delete the tags (for Automated Builds) on your own. Please contact support@docker.com asking them to delete the tag.

Also, you should refrain from using `HTTP DELETE` request for Docker Hub. These API Endpoints are only meant for private registry and not for Docker Hub till date. Docker is planning to release the V2 registry Endpoint soon, after which you can safely use the API calls to delete/manipulate tags and images. Until then do not use V1/V2 Endpoints for deleting tags.